# Proving Infinite Limit from Definition, Floor Function

Tags: limits, proof-writing, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I want to formally prove that the function $$f(x)=\textrm{floor}\left(\frac{1}{\pi}\left(x-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\right)$$ tends to infinity as $x\rightarrow\infty$. More specifically, I am having trouble finding a value for N in the statement $$\forall M \exists N(x>N\rightarrow f(x)>M)$$
that will allow me to prove that $f(x)>N$ assuming that $x>N$.

Comment: Just use that $$\lfloor x\rfloor\gt x-1$$

Comment: I'm not sure I understand...

Comment: The floor of any number is strictly greater than that number minus one. So we can just say$$f(x)\gt \frac1{\pi}\left(x-\frac{\pi}2\right)-1$$and the latter function is clearly unbounded (take $x\gt\pi(M+1)+\frac{\pi}2$).